# Angular8 - Switch between two modules in prod

Tags: angular, architecture, web-deployment

I'm working on a website that has on the front end 3 parts

- main Web app
- admin Web app
- angular package with common components, services and so on.

That worked fine until now. Bu, as the project got larger I find it difficult to maintain the common library, since I have to rebuild and so on.

Is there a possibility to have one angular app that can switch between the main app module and the admin one with a command line switch?

On deployment I just run the angular apps in two separate docker containers and I need to be on different subdomains.

Thanks,
David

Comment: have you tested if `ng serve --port=4201` on the second app might work for you? I think there might be some problems while compiling but maybe you can use this to tests both apps locally at the same time. Angular CLI does not support serving multiple applications at once > https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12181

Comment: Hi, it's not a problem of testing, but rather of developing.
I am aware of - - port option on ng.

What I do right now:
 - I run npm package on my library, which creates a tzr.gz package
 - then I install it in my apps with plain npm install from the local disk

The problem is that it's very time consuming to make changes in dev mode.

And that's what I'm trying to achieve here